# Tick time calculation with signed values

Tags: c

How can I get rid of the potential overflow check if I use signed integers?

```
unsigned long ticks1 = GetTickCount();
if (SemaphoreTake(_sema, to)) // taken
{
    unsigned long ticks2 = GetTickCount();
    // take care of potential overflow
    unsigned long elapsed = ticks2 > ticks1 ? (ticks2 - ticks1) : (ticks1 - ticks2);
    // return rest time
    return elapsed < to ? to - elapsed : 0;
}
else // timed out
    return 0;
```

Comment: `unsigned long long tick` ? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the overflow check.  Should `ticks2 < ticks1`, unsigned math subtraction is well defined in C with the result mathematically the same as `elapsed = (ULONG_MAX + 1) + ticks2 - ticks1`.  Certainly do *not* want `ticks1 - ticks2`.

```
// unsigned long elapsed = ticks2 > ticks1 ? (ticks2 - ticks1):(ticks1 - ticks2);
unsigned long elapsed = ticks2 - ticks1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx** says to use GetTickCount64() if the time interval you are working with is more than 49.7 days, or check for an overflow condition when comparing times. So maybe you just need to limit yourself to 49.7 days if you don't want to make the check.